# Chromium drop down/select list behavior is erratic

Tags: jquery, html, css, chromium

So in my time as a web developer, I've never seen anything like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/28Xsm/18/

The `/* comment */` in the JS indicates where the problem manifests in the JS. It appears to be a combination between this action and `nth-of-type`.

In Chrome (or Chromium-based browsers), if you click the module dropdown and attempt to change it, you'll find that once per second, it appears to reselect the selected option. This means that it will also scroll back up if you're scrolled down in that second. This is "clearly" the fault of the code executing once per second on an interval, however, only the lines that remove the classes from the unrelated DOM elements cause the issue to present.

Non-Chromium browsers I've tested (of which, I mean IE9+ and Firefox) have had no problems with the very same markup/CSS/JS. I also tried xombrero, and it doesn't seem like WebKit inherently carries the same issue. I'm using Windows 7 Pro. My Chrome has no extensions installed outside of Google Docs (and I'm not sure when that got there) and the same issue appears on both Comodo and Opera 17.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here? Am I using something like a fool, is there a bug in jQuery that causes this for Chromium only somehow, or is this just a really strange Chromium behavior?

Comment: The problem you describe doesn't happen for me on Chrome (on Mac, latest version): can change things in the drop down, scroll down, nothing unexpected happens, drop-down keeps the same option. Is it possible that a Chrome extension could be involved? Also, it'd be worth finding out if it happens on any [other Webkit browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based) or if it's just Chrome

Comment: Its happening for me, I removed your session function and that fixed it, but after reviewing the session functions I don't see anything that would cause the issue.

Comment: The part of the session function that triggers the problem is the part at `true ||`. Getting more webkit/Chromium-based browsers now to test the repro.

Comment: Good call on browsers, I was able to reproduce the same issue in Comodo. I tried out xombrero and it doesn't have the same problem. I've added platform information to the question. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is occuring here, Chrome 32 dev. @user568458 try selecting an option, closing the menu, then re-open the menu and hold your mouse  over another option, and you should see the issue.